# how can i solve the missing player score argument form the draw leaderboard function

Tags: python, position, missing-features

main(this is the code that creates my games and creates a score):

```
# importing package
import turtle
import random 
import sys
import time
import leaderboard as lb





# set the background color of the turtle screen
backround = turtle.Screen()
backround.bgcolor("forest green")
backround.tracer(False)
backround.setup(600,8000)

#score configureation
score = 0
leader_names_list = []
leader_scores_list = []
leaderboard_file_name = "a122_leaderboard.txt"
player_name = input ("Please enter your name:")


#variables 
style = ('Comic Sans MS', 18, 'bold')


#display score


scorewriter = turtle.Turtle()
scorewriter.hideturtle()
scorewriter.penup()
scorewriter.goto(-170, 180)
scorewriter.pendown()
scorewriter.showturtle()





#create net
net = turtle.Turtle()
net.color("white")
net.hideturtle()
net.pensize(15)
net.penup()
net.goto(-250,375)
net.pendown()
net.goto(250,375)
net.goto(250,175)
net.penup()
net.goto(-250,375)
net.pendown()
net.goto(-250,175)

#create goalie
goal = []
backround.addshape("goal.gif")
goalie = turtle.Turtle()
goalie.speed(7)
goal.append(goalie)
goalie.shape("goal.gif")
goalie.penup()
goalie.goto(0,210)
goalie.setheading(270)

#create Soccer Ball
ball = []
backround.addshape("soccer.gif")
sb = turtle.Turtle()
sb.speed(7)
ball.append(sb)
sb.shape("soccer.gif")
sb.penup()
sb.goto(130,0)
sb.setheading(90)


#create goal line
goal_line = []
gl = turtle.Turtle() 
goal_line.append(gl)
gl.shape("square")  
gl.penup()
gl.goto(0,180)
gl.shapesize(1,25,1)
gl.hideturtle()

#create left boundary
left_boundary = []
lbnd = turtle.Turtle() 
left_boundary.append(lb)
lbnd.shape("square")  
lbnd.penup()
lbnd.goto(-250,-90)
lbnd.shapesize(30,1,1)
lbnd.hideturtle()

#create right boundary
right_boundary = []
rb = turtle.Turtle() 
right_boundary.append(rb)
rb.shape("square")  
rb.penup()
rb.goto(250,-90)
rb.shapesize(30,1,1)
rb.hideturtle()

#Create left button
lbutton = turtle.Turtle()

lbutton.shape('circle')
lbutton.fillcolor('red')
lbutton.shapesize(5)
lbutton.penup()
lbutton.goto(-200, -200)

#create middle button
mbutton = turtle.Turtle()

mbutton.shape('circle')
mbutton.fillcolor('red')
mbutton.shapesize(5)
mbutton.penup()
mbutton.goto(0, -200)

#create right button
rbutton = turtle.Turtle()

rbutton.shape('circle')
rbutton.fillcolor('red')
rbutton.shapesize(5)
rbutton.penup()
rbutton.goto(200, -200)

#create text
t = turtle.Turtle()
t.hideturtle()

t.penup()
t.goto(-200,-275)
t.pendown()
t.write('Dribble Left!', font=style, align='center')
t.penup()
t.goto(0,-275)
t.pendown()
t.write('Shoot Straight!', font=style, align='center')
t.penup()
t.goto(200,-275)
t.pendown()
t.write('Dribble Right!', font=style, align='center')

#end tracer
backround.update()
backround.tracer(True)

#functions 
def update_score_for_frog():
    global score
    score =  score +1
    scorewriter.clear()
    scorewriter.write(score, font = style)   

def manage_leaderboard():
  global leader_scores_list
  global leader_names_list
  global score
  lb.load_leaderboard(leaderboard_file_name, leader_names_list, leader_scores_list)
  if (len(leader_scores_list) < 5 or score > leader_scores_list[4]):
    lb.update_leaderboard(leaderboard_file_name, leader_names_list, leader_scores_list, player_name, score)
    lb.draw_leaderboard(leader_names_list, leader_scores_list, True, score)
  
  else:
    lb.draw_leaderboard(leader_names_list, leader_scores_list, False, score) 

def GoalieMovement(x, y):
    '''
    #n = random.randint(1,3)
    # n == 1:
        #goalie.goto(-200,210)
    #if n == 2:
        #goalie.goto(0,210)
    #if n == 3:
        #goalie.goto(200,210)
    '''
     
def left(x,y):
    leftb()
    GoalieMovement(x,y)
    sb.setheading(180)
    sb.forward(30)
    scorekeeper()

def straight(x, y):

    GoalieMovement(x,y)
    sb.setheading(90)
    sb.forward(30)
    scorekeeper()

def right(x, y):
    rightb()
    GoalieMovement(x,y)
    sb.setheading(0)
    sb.forward(30)
    scorekeeper()

#create boundary functions  
def leftb():
    if ((lbnd.xcor() + (sb.xcor())) == -420 ):
        wtxt = turtle.Turtle()
        wtxt.hideturtle()
        wtxt.speed(0)
        wtxt.penup()
        wtxt.goto(0,100)
        wtxt.pendown()
        wtxt.write('Out of Bounds!', font=style, align='center')
        wtxt.penup()
        wtxt.goto(0,0)
        wtxt.pendown()
        wtxt.write('GAME OVER!', font=style, align='center')
        time.sleep(5)
        manage_leaderboard()
        
def rightb():
    if (((rb.xcor()) + (sb.xcor())) == 650):
        wtxt = turtle.Turtle()
        wtxt.hideturtle()
        wtxt.speed(0)
        wtxt.penup()
        wtxt.goto(0,100)
        wtxt.pendown()
        wtxt.write('Out Of Bounds!', font=style, align='center')
        wtxt.penup()
        wtxt.goto(0,0)
        wtxt.pendown()
        wtxt.write('GAME OVER!', font=style, align='center')
        time.sleep(5)
        manage_leaderboard()
def scorekeeper():
    if ((abs(goalie.ycor()) - abs(sb.ycor())) < 10 ) and ((abs(goalie.xcor()) - abs(sb.xcor())) < 10 ) :
        wtxt = turtle.Turtle()
        wtxt.hideturtle()
        wtxt.speed(0)
        wtxt.penup()
        wtxt.goto(0,100)
        wtxt.pendown()
        wtxt.write('Saved By The Keeper!', font=style, align='center')
        wtxt.penup()
        wtxt.goto(0,0)
        wtxt.pendown()
        wtxt.write('GAME OVER!', font=style, align='center')
        time.sleep(5)
        wtxt.hideturtle()
        scorewriter.hideturtle()
        sb.hideturtle()
        goalie.hideturtle()
        net.hideturtle()
        gl.hideturtle()
        lbutton.hideturtle()
        mbutton.hideturtle()
        rbutton.hideturtle()
        t.hideturtle()
        manage_leaderboard()
        
    if ((abs(gl.ycor()) - abs(sb.ycor())) < 10 ):
        sb.goto(130,0)
        goalie.goto(0,210)
        update_score_for_frog()
""" 
        qtxt = turtle.Turtle()
        qtxt.hideturtle()
        qtxt.penup()
        qtxt.speed(0)
        qtxt.goto(0,100)
        qtxt.pendown()
        qtxt.write('Goal!', font=style, align='center')
"""
#create clickable buttons
lbutton.onclick(left)
mbutton.onclick(straight)
rbutton.onclick(right)



#screen
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.mainloop()
```

leaderboard(this stores the score from the previous code and creates a leaderboard):

```
def load_leaderboard(file_name, leader_names, leader_scores):

  leaderboard_file = open(file_name, "r")  
  
  for line in leaderboard_file:
    leader_name = ""
    leader_score = ""  
    index = 0
    '''

    while (line[index] != ","):
      leader_name = leader_name + line[index] 
      index = index + 1
      print("leader name is:", leader_name)
    '''
    while (line[index] != ",") and (index < len(index)):
     leader_name = leader_name + line[index] 
     index = index + 1
     print("leader name is:", leader_name)


    leader_name.append(leader_name)
    
    while (line[index] != "\n"):
      print(leader_score)
    
    leader_score.append(int(leader_score))

    leaderboard_file.close()


def update_leaderboard(file_name, leader_names, leader_scores, player_name, player_score):

  leader_index = 0
  while (leader_index < len(leader_scores)):

    if (player_score >= leader_scores[leader_index]):
      break
    else:
      leader_index = leader_index + 1
  
  leader_scores.insert(leader_index, player_score)
  leader_names.insert(leader_index, player_name)

  print("leader_names are:", leader_names)
  print("leader_scores are:", leader_scores)

  if (len(leader_names) == 6):
    leader_names.pop()
  if (len(leader_scores) == 6):
    leader_scores.pop()
  
  leaderboard_file = open(file_name, "w")  
  leader_index = 0
  
  
  while (leader_index < len(leader_names)):
    leaderboard_file.write(leader_names[leader_index] + "," + str(leader_scores       [leader_index]) + "\n") 
    leader_index = leader_index + 1
  
  leaderboard_file.close()
  

def draw_leaderboard(leader_names, leader_scores, high_scorer, turtle_object, player_score):
  
  font_setup = ("Arial", 20, "normal")
  turtle_object.clear()
  turtle_object.penup()
  turtle_object.goto(-200,100)
  turtle_object.hideturtle()
  turtle_object.down()
  leader_index = 0

  while leader_index < len(leader_names):
    turtle_object.write(str(leader_index + 1) + "\t" + leader_names[leader_index] + "\t" + str(leader_scores[leader_index]), font=font_setup)
    turtle_object.penup()
    turtle_object.goto(-200,int(turtle_object.ycor())-50)
    turtle_object.down()
    leader_index = leader_index + 1

  if (high_scorer):
    turtle_object.write("Congratulations! You made the leaderboard!", font=font_setup)
  else:
    turtle_object.write("Sorry, you didn't make the leaderboard. Maybe next time!", font=font_setup)

  turtle_object.penup()
  turtle_object.goto(-200,int(turtle_object.ycor())-50)
  turtle_object.pendown()
```

error:

```
File "/Users/Final.py", line 191, in left
    leftb()
  File "/Users/Final.py", line 226, in leftb
    manage_leaderboard()
  File "/Users/Final.py", line 174, in manage_leaderboard
    lb.draw_leaderboard(leader_names_list, leader_scores_list, True, score)
TypeError: draw_leaderboard() missing 1 required positional argument: 'player_score'
```

I'm confused about why it is getting the player_score error and what I could add to make my code work. this missing argument is preventing my code from storing the score received from running the main code to storing in the a122_leaderboard.txt file.

Comment: you define `def draw_leaderboard(leader_names, leader_scores, high_scorer, turtle_object, player_score):`  with 5 arguments but you run `lb.draw_leaderboard(leader_names_list, leader_scores_list, True, score)` with 4 arguments - probably you forgot `turtle`.

Answer (score 0):

You define with 5 arguments

```
def draw_leaderboard(leader_names, leader_scores, high_scorer, turtle_object, player_score):
```

but you run with 4 values

```
lb.draw_leaderboard(leader_names_list, leader_scores_list, True, score)
```

As for me you forgot value for `turtle_object`